# Conflict between significance and importance. A paradox

Tags: random-forest, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, paradox

When examining a set of proteins of healthy controls and patients I found significant differences using the Mann-Whitney test. However, when I used Random Forest, the most 'important' proteins for classification included some proteins that did not vary significantly with the Mann-Whitney test, and viceversa, many proteins that varied significantly  with the Mann-Whitney test (with p<0.00001) were NOT identified as important by Random Forest. This is an authentic paradox. I found no references in the literature about this apparent contradiction, and I do not know how to interpret it. This also raises the question of which are the true candidate markers of the disease: the differentially expressed proteins identified by univariate tests or the proteins important for multivariate classification.
Thanks for answers.

---

Random Forest was run plain, with two groups of controls and patients only. I used both packages available in R (randomForest and randomForestSRC) obtaining the same results. In fact the classification generated by RF is the best ever obtained for that set of subjects. But I am very uncertain whether and how to interpret the importance of the variables for diagnostic purposes, given the strong contrast with Mann-Whitney tests.

Comment: What was your Random Forest model?  Surely it included factors other than "control" and "patient" which were not part of the Mann-Whitney test setup.  Also, RF importance is not a formal statistical test and can be misleading for a number of reasons.

Comment: What features did you have in your RF?  I don't see how you could have run it with just one feature "Control / Patient"...

Comment: I have 76 proteins of two groups, controls and patients. Maybe Dariober (below) solved the problem. In conclusion, Random Forest is still one of the best classificatory methods, but the logic of the decisional trees, which can use multiple split points of the same feature, prevents the consideration of proteins that are 'important' for classifcation also as diagnostic makers of the disease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with random forest but I think a possible explanation is that random forest picks up non-linear associations between control and treatment which are "invisible" to a test for differences in means or ranks between groups. If these non-linear associations are very important, than the associations detected by Mann-Whitney test may appear small.

This is a simulated example. Protein `p0` is very well associated to the *Control* group when it is lowly or highly expressed. This is picked up by random forest but missed by t-test. `p6` instead is generally higher in *Patient* group but not too strongly (p= 0.05, t-test). I also add some noise proteins :

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(randomForest)

set.seed(1234)
grp <- c(rep('C', 10), rep('P', 20), rep('C', 10))
prot <- 1:length(grp)
dat <- data.table(
    grp, 
    p0= 1:length(grp) + rnorm(length(grp), sd= 0.1),
    p1= rnorm(n= length(grp)),
    p2= rnorm(n= length(grp)),
    p3= rnorm(n= length(grp)),
    p4= rnorm(n= length(grp)),
    p5= rnorm(n= length(grp)),
    p6= as.numeric(as.factor(grp)) + rnorm(length(grp), sd= 1)
    )
dat[, grp := as.factor(grp)]
dat
    grp    p0      p1     p2     p3     p4     p5     p6
 1:   C  0.88  1.4495 -0.178 -0.191 -0.847  0.485  1.059
 2:   C  2.03 -1.0686 -0.170 -0.782 -0.261  0.697  1.413
 3:   C  3.11 -0.8554 -1.372  2.058 -0.414  0.186 -0.098
 4:   C  3.77 -0.2806 -0.174  0.751 -0.183  0.701  1.711
 5:   C  5.04 -0.9943  0.850  1.824  0.407  0.312  1.719
 6:   C  6.05 -0.9685  0.698  0.080  0.625  0.760  1.252
 7:   C  6.94 -1.1073  0.550 -0.631  1.678  1.842  2.357
 8:   C  7.95 -1.2520 -0.403 -1.513 -0.069  1.112  1.404
 9:   C  8.94 -0.5238 -0.192 -0.636 -0.321  0.033  1.264
10:   C  9.91 -0.4968 -1.195  0.226  1.471 -1.114  1.268
11:   P 10.95 -1.8060 -0.053  1.014  1.704  0.418  2.437
12:   P 11.90 -0.5821  0.255  0.253  0.043 -0.400  3.060
13:   P 12.92 -1.1089  1.706 -1.172 -0.333  1.493  2.452
14:   P 14.01 -1.0150  1.002  0.669 -1.822 -1.607  2.663
15:   P 15.10 -0.1623 -0.496 -1.650  1.411 -0.416  0.864
16:   P 15.99  0.5631  0.356 -0.366 -0.838  0.422  1.630
...
...
```

T-tests for associations: `p0` shows no association, `p6` weak association:

```
p0 <- t.test(dat[grp=='C']$p0, dat[grp=='P']$p0) # p-value ~ 1
p6 <- t.test(dat[grp=='C']$p6, dat[grp=='P']$p6) # p-value ~ 0.05
```

Instead random forest shows good importance for `p0`:

```
rf <- randomForest(grp ~ ., data= dat, importance= TRUE)
imp <- importance(rf)
imp
       C     P MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
p0 16.75 17.99                18.98              6.8
p1  0.11  1.58                 0.79              2.2
p2  3.62  1.48                 3.15              2.2
p3  0.96  1.29                 1.49              2.3
p4 -0.71 -0.96                -0.75              1.7
p5  1.98 -2.59                -0.31              1.5
p6  5.13  4.25                 5.84              2.7
```

Some plots of the data:

```
gg <- ggplot(data= dat, aes(x= p0, y= p6, colour= grp, label= grp)) +
    geom_text() +
    theme_light() +
    theme(legend.position= 'none')

par(mfrow= c(1, 2)) 
boxplot(p0 ~ grp, data= dat)
boxplot(p6 ~ grp, data= dat)
```

[image]

[image]